# Vectorizing sums of different diagonals in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, dynamic-programming, vectorization

I want to vectorize the following MATLAB code.  I think it must be simple but I'm finding it confusing nevertheless.

```
r = some constant less than m or n
[m,n] = size(C);
S = zeros(m-r,n-r);
for i=1:m-r+1
    for j=1:n-r+1
        S(i,j) = sum(diag(C(i:i+r-1,j:j+r-1)));
    end
end
```

The code calculates a table of scores, **S**, for a dynamic programming algorithm, from another score table, **C**.
The diagonal summing is to generate scores for individual pieces of the data used to generate **C**, for all possible pieces (of size r).

Thanks in advance for any answers!  Sorry if this one should be obvious...

**Note**
The built-in conv2 turned out to be faster than convnfft, because my eye(r) is quite small ( 5 <= r <= 20 ).  convnfft.m states that r should be > 20 for any benefit to manifest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to calculate the diagonal sum of every subarray of C, where you have removed the last row and column of C (if you should not remove the row/col, you need to loop to m-r+1, and you need to pass the entire array C to the function in my solution below).

You can do this operation via a [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), like so:

```
S = conv2(C(1:end-1,1:end-1),eye(r),'valid');
```

If C and r are large, you may want to have a look at [CONVNFFT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution) from the Matlab File Exchange to speed up calculations.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.
I will look at CONVNFFT tomorrow.  On the subset of data I use for testing (approx. 500 times smaller than real data) the built-in conv2 function achieves a 69,652 times reduction in the number of calls and 34.56 times decrease in execution time in comparison to the loops (23.5 vs 0.68 s).

Answer (score 3):

Based on the idea of [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863751/vectorizing-sums-of-different-diagonals-in-a-matrix/2864135#2864135), and as [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232610/jonas) pointed out in the comments, this can be done in two lines using `IM2COL` with some array manipulation:

```
B = im2col(C, [r r], 'sliding');
S = reshape( sum(B(1:r+1:end,:)), size(C)-r+1 );
```

Basically `B` contains the elements of all sliding blocks of size r-by-r over the matrix `C`. Then we take the elements on the diagonal of each of these blocks `B(1:r+1:end,:)`, compute their sum, and reshape the result to the expected size.

---

Comparing this to the convolution-based solution by Jonas, this does not perform any matrix multiplication, only indexing...

Comment: If you can afford the memory, im2col is usually a great way to go.

Comment: im2col returns values rather than indices, so the second line should have `reshape( sum(B(1:r+1:end,:)) ),size(C)-r+1);`.

Comment: @reve_etrange: you are absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I've also now benchmarked `conv2` vs. `im2col` & `reshape`. Wrote a function taking arguments for `size(C)` and `r`, which preallocates answers and tries each method ten times.  Looks like `conv2` is faster, regardless of `size(C)`, `r` combinations.  I assume it's because the `im2col` matrix is quite large.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you might need to rearrange C into a 3D matrix before summing it along one of the dimensions. I'll post with an answer shortly.

**EDIT**

I didn't manage to find a way to vectorise it cleanly, but I did find the function `accumarray`, which might be of some help. I'll look at it in more detail when I am home.

**EDIT#2**

Found a simpler solution by using linear indexing, but this could be memory-intensive.

At C(1,1), the indexes we want to sum are 1+[0, m+1, 2*m+2, 3*m+3, 4*m+4, ... ], or (0:r-1)+(0:m:(r-1)*m)

```
sum_ind = (0:r-1)+(0:m:(r-1)*m);
```

create `S_offset`, an (m-r) by (n-r) by r matrix, such that S_offset(:,:,1) = 0, S_offset(:,:,2) = m+1, S_offset(:,:,3) = 2*m+2, and so on.

```
S_offset = permute(repmat( sum_ind, [m-r, 1, n-r] ), [1, 3, 2]);
```

create `S_base`, a matrix of base array addresses from which the offset will be calculated.

```
S_base = reshape(1:m*n,[m n]);
S_base = repmat(S_base(1:m-r,1:n-r), [1, 1, r]);
```

Finally, use `S_base+S_offset` to address the values of C.

```
S = sum(C(S_base+S_offset), 3);
```

You can, of course, use `bsxfun` and other methods to make it more efficient; here I chose to lay it out for clarity. I have yet to benchmark this to see how it compares with the double-loop method though; I need to head home for dinner first!

Comment: Hm, with the diagonal from a 2D index becoming the third dimension at that index?

Comment: @JS: Nice idea. `im2col` could probably save you a few lines of code here.

Comment: @Jonas: I added a solution that does that exactly!

Comment: Looking at the online documentation, im2col would definitely save a few lines of code; pity I didn't have the required toolbox. Perhaps I should look into getting a few additional toolboxes at the end of this year.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? This function adds the diagonals and puts them into a vector similar to how the function 'sum' adds up all of the columns in a matrix and puts them into a vector.

```
function [diagSum] = diagSumCalc(squareMatrix, LLUR0_ULLR1)
% 
% Input: squareMatrix: A square matrix.
%        LLUR0_ULLR1:  LowerLeft to UpperRight addition = 0     
%                      UpperLeft to LowerRight addition = 1
% 
% Output: diagSum: A vector of the sum of the diagnols of the matrix.
% 
% Example: 
% 
% >> squareMatrix = [1 2 3; 
%                    4 5 6;
%                    7 8 9];
% 
% >> diagSum = diagSumCalc(squareMatrix, 0);
% 
% diagSum = 
% 
%       1 6 15 14 9
% 
% >> diagSum = diagSumCalc(squareMatrix, 1);
% 
% diagSum = 
% 
%       7 12 15 8 3
% 
% Written by M. Phillips
% Oct. 16th, 2013
% MIT Open Source Copywrite
% Contact mphillips@hmc.edu fmi.
% 

if (nargin < 2)
    disp('Error on input. Needs two inputs.');
    return;
end

if (LLUR0_ULLR1 ~= 0 && LLUR0_ULLR1~= 1)
    disp('Error on input. Only accepts 0 or 1 as input for second condition.');
    return;
end

[M, N] = size(squareMatrix);

if (M ~= N)
    disp('Error on input. Only accepts a square matrix as input.');
    return;
end

diagSum = zeros(1, M+N-1);

if LLUR0_ULLR1 == 1
    squareMatrix = rot90(squareMatrix, -1);
end

for i = 1:length(diagSum)
    if i <= M
        countUp = 1;
        countDown = i;
        while countDown ~= 0
            diagSum(i) = squareMatrix(countUp, countDown) + diagSum(i);
            countUp = countUp+1;
            countDown = countDown-1;
        end
    end
    if i > M
        countUp = i-M+1;
        countDown = M;
        while countUp ~= M+1
            diagSum(i) = squareMatrix(countUp, countDown) + diagSum(i);
            countUp = countUp+1;
            countDown = countDown-1;
        end
    end
end
```

Cheers