# Parallelize or vectorize all-against-all operation on a large number of matrices?

Tags: matlab, dynamic-programming, vectorization, parallel-processing

I have approximately 5,000 matrices with the same number of rows and varying numbers of columns (20 x ~200).  Each of these matrices must be compared against every other in a dynamic programming algorithm.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863751/vectorizing-sums-of-different-diagonals-in-a-matrix) question, I asked how to perform the comparison quickly and was given an excellent answer involving a 2D convolution.  Serially, iteratively applying that method, like so

```
list = who('data_matrix_prefix*')
H = cell(numel(list),numel(list));  
for i=1:numel(list)
    for j=1:numel(list)
        if i ~= j
            eval([ 'H{i,j} = compare(' char(list(i)) ',' char(list(j)) ');']);
        end
    end
end
```

is fast for small subsets of the data (e.g. for 9 matrices, 9*9 - 9 = 72 calls are made in ~1 s, 870 calls in ~2.5 s).
However, operating on all the data requires almost 25 million calls.
I have also tried using deal() to make a cell array composed entirely of the next element in data, so I could use cellfun() in a single loop:

```
# who(), load() and struct2cell() calls place k data matrices in a 1D cell array called data.
nextData = cell(k,1);
for i=1:k
    [nextData{:}] = deal(data{i});
    H{:,i} = cellfun(@compare,data,nextData,'UniformOutput',false);
end
```

Unfortunately, this is not really any faster, because all the time is in compare().  Both of these code examples seem ill-suited for parallelization.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to make my variables sliced.
compare() is totally vectorized; it uses matrix multiplication and conv2() exclusively (I am under the impression that all of these operations, including the cellfun(), should be multithreaded in MATLAB?).

Does anyone see a (explicitly) parallelized solution or better vectorization of the problem?

**Note**
I realize both my examples are inefficient - the first would be twice as fast if it calculated a triangular cell array, and the second is still calculating the self comparisons, as well.  But the time savings for a good parallelization are more like a factor of 16 (or 72 if I install MATLAB on everyone's machines).

**Aside**
There is also a memory issue.  I used a couple of evals to append each column of H into a file, with names like H1, H2, etc. and then clear H<sub>i</sub>.  Unfortunately, the saves are very slow...

Comment: What does `compare` do? What is an example row of the list?

Comment: For data matrices A and B it calculates A' * B and convolves the product with an identity matrix.  
The matrices are normalized; rows and columns contain values from 0 to 1 that sum to 1.  
The matrix resulting from compare contains values from -30 to 30 which roughly follow an extreme value distribution.

Comment: What's the reason to use `eval`, then?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood.  The variable I called list above has the names of the matrices as its rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example can be easily sliced for use with the Parallel Processing Toolbox. This toolbox distributes iterations of your code among up to 8 different local processors. If you want to run the code on a cluster, you also need the Distributed Computing Toolbox.

```
%# who(), load() and struct2cell() calls place k data matrices in a 1D cell array called data.

parfor i=1:k-1 %# this will run the loop in parallel with the parallel processing toolbox
    %# only make the necessary comparisons
    H{i+1:k,i} = cellfun(@compare,data(i+1:k),repmat(data(i),k-i,1),'UniformOutput',false);

    %# if the above doesn't work, try this
    hSlice = cell(k,1);
    hSlice{i+1:k} = cellfun(@compare,data(i+1:k),repmat(data(i),k-i,1),'UniformOutput',false);
    H{:,i} = hSlice;
end
```

Comment: "PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way nextData is used."  
Also it doesn't want to slice data (which is a 1D cell array).

Comment: It won't slice `data`, because you use the entire array `data` in your call to cellfun. Also, I fixed the problem with `nextData`

Comment: Thank you...now M-Lint is happy.  But can repmat return a cell array repeating element of data?  It is concatenating them all together and creating a large matrix.

Comment: @reve_etrange. D'oh! You need to do repmat with data(i) instead data{i}. Fixed

Comment: @reve_etrange: I've also updated the solution so that you only make the necessary comparisons

Comment: Thanks again Jonas. The first way still has an issue with the indexing of H, I think that in a parfor the loop variable must be used as only one index. Also data (first occurrence) is still not sliced.  I guess that because each iteration is sent two, non-overlapping parts of data it wants to send the entire thing?

Comment: @reve_etrange: `data` would be sliced only if it was exclusively indexed with `i`. If more than that is needed, all of data is passed to each worker and the variable is not sliced. Variables not being sliced is not necessarily a problem. Also, I thought the first way may be problematic, so I suggested the second one. I'm glad it works. Note that it only makes the comparisons below the diagonal.

Comment: I just calculated the memory usage for duplicate copies of the data; it's no problem.  Now to combine with the out-of-memory version...in which case the triangular indexing remains essential.

Answer (score 3):

Does

```
compare(a,b) == compare(b,a)
```

and

```
compare(a,a) == 1
```

If so, change your loop

```
for i=1:numel(list)
    for j=1:numel(list)
    ...
    end
end
```

to

```
for i=1:numel(list)
    for j= i+1 : numel(list)
    ...
    end
end
```

and deal with the symmetry and identity case.  This will cut your calculation time by half.

Comment: The symmetry cases are transposes and the identity case is not 1, but is not useful.  Thanks, I think it will help my memory troubles as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have to perform 5000^2 matrix comparisons ?  Rather than try to parallelise the compare function, perhaps you should think of your problem being composed of 5000^2 tasks ?  The Matlab Parallel Compute Toolbox supports task-based parallelism. Unfortunately my experience with PCT is with parallelisation of large linear algebra type problems so I can't really tell you much more than that.  The documentation will undoubtedly help you more.