# Out-of-memory algorithms for addressing large arrays

Tags: matlab, file-io, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to deal with a very large dataset.  I have k = ~4200 matrices (varying sizes) which must be compared combinatorially, skipping non-unique and self comparisons.  Each of k(k-1)/2 comparisons produces a matrix, which must be indexed against its parents (i.e. can find out where it came from).  The convenient way to do this is to (triangularly) fill a k-by-k cell array with the result of each comparison.  These are ~100 X ~100 matrices, on average.  Using single precision floats, it works out to 400 GB overall.
I need to 1) generate the cell array or pieces of it without trying to place the whole thing in memory and 2) access its elements (and *their* elements) in like fashion.  My attempts have been inefficient due to reliance on MATLAB's `eval()` as well as `save` and `clear` occurring in loops.

```
for i=1:k
    [~,m] = size(data{i});
    cur_var = ['H' int2str(i)];
    %# if i == 1; save('FileName'); end; %# If using a single MAT file and need to create it.
    eval([cur_var ' = cell(1,k-i);']);
    for j=i+1:k
        [~,n] = size(data{j});
        eval([cur_var '{i,j} = zeros(m,n,''single'');']);
        eval([cur_var '{i,j} = compare(data{i},data{j});']);
    end
    save(cur_var,cur_var); %# Add '-append' when using a single MAT file.
    clear(cur_var);
end
```

The other thing I have done is to perform the split when `mod((i+j-1)/2,max(factor(k(k-1)/2))) == 0`.  This divides the result into the largest number of same-size pieces, which seems logical.  The indexing is a little more complicated, but not too bad because a linear index could be used.

Does anyone know/see a better way?

Comment: In this question I/we are trying to make an in-memory version /fast/: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872249/parallelize-or-vectorize-all-against-all-operation-on-a-large-number-of-matrices

Comment: It's a bad practice using `EVAL` to create variables with dynamically generated names, use `STRUCT` with dynamic field references instead: http://matlabwiki.mathworks.com/MATLAB_FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that combines going fast with using minimal memory.

I use fwrite/fread so that you still can use `parfor` (and this time, I made sure it works :) )

```
%# assume data is loaded an k is known

%# find the index pairs for comparisons. This could be done more elegantly, I guess.
%# I'm constructing a lower triangular array, i.e. an array that has ones wherever
%# we want to compare i (row) and j (col). Then I use find to get i and j
[iIdx,jIdx] = find(tril(ones(k,k),-1));

%# create a directory to store the comparisons
mkdir('H_matrix_elements')
savePath = fullfile(pwd,'H_matrix_elements');

%# loop through all comparisons in parallel. This way there may be a bit more overhead from
%# the individual function calls. However, parfor is most efficient if there are 
%# a lot of relatively similarly fast iterations.
parfor ct = 1:length(iIdx)

   %# make the comparison - do double b/c there shouldn't be a memory issue 
   currentComparison = compare(data{iIdx(ct)},data{jIdx{ct});

   %# create save-name as H_i_j, e.g. H_104_23
   saveName = fullfile(savePath,sprintf('H_%i_%i',iIdx(ct),jIdx(ct)));

   %# save. Since 'save' is not allowed, use fwrite to write the data to disk
   fid = fopen(saveName,'w');

   %# for simplicity: save data as vector, add two elements to the beginning
   %# to store the size of the array
   fwrite(fid,[size(currentComparison)';currentComparison(:)]);  % ' #SO formatting

   %# close file
   fclose(fid)
end



%# to read e.g. comparison H_104_23
fid = fopen(fullfile(savePath,'H_104_23'),'r');
tmp = fread(fid);
fclose(fid);

%# reshape into 2D array.
data = reshape(tmp(3:end),tmp(1),tmp(2));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `save()` can't be called in a `parfor`.

Comment: @reve_etrange: Oops. Ah well, you have to use e.g. fwrite, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `eval` and `clear` calls by assigning the filename separately.

```
for i=1:k
    [~,m] = size(data{i});
    file_name = ['H' int2str(i)];    
    cur_var = cell(1, k-i);
    for j=i+1:k
        [~,n] = size(data{j});
        cur_var{i,j} = zeros(m, n, 'single');
        cur_var{i,j} = compare(data{i}, data{j});
    end
    save(file_name, cur_var); 
end
```

If you need the saved variables to take different names, use the `-struct` option to save.

```
str.(file_name);
save(file_name, '-struct', str);
```